# Doubt in Fourier Series

Tags: fourier-series

When we solve the equation $$\frac 2{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}k\sin(nx)dx;$$ after integrating it, we get $\frac {2k}{n\pi}(1-\cos n\pi)$. Why is $\cos n\pi=(-1)^n$?

Comment: Look at the graph of $cos x$.

Comment: $\cos 0=1$, $\cos \pi=-1$, $\cos 2\pi=1$, ...

Comment: Oh.. i did'nt think of that. Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 2):

The cosine is $2\pi$ periodic and has maxima at $2\pi k$ for $k \in \mathbb Z$ and minima at $\pi (2k+1)$ for $k \in \mathbb Z$. So $\cos n \pi$ is always at a maximum or minimum for $n \in \mathbb Z$.

I think if you draw it you will see it even better:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is basic trigonometry:

$$\begin{align*}&\cos 0=1\implies \cos(0+2n\pi)=\cos 2n\pi=1\\
&\cos \pi=1\implies \cos(\pi+2n\pi)=\cos((2n+1)\pi)=-1\end{align*}\;\;\implies \cos(n\pi)=(-1)^n$$